# Based on whether checkbox is ticked, show another form question

Tags: angular

I'm creating a form in angular and one of the questions is a multi-select question. The subsequent question should only be visible if an option is selected in the previous question.

Previously, I had been doing this:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="selector">
      <mat-select placeholder="Q1"
        formControlName="Q1" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value" (click)="setBool(true)">
          {{ option.value }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="selector" *ngIf="bool">
      <mat-select placeholder="Q2"
        formControlName="q2">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.value">
          {{ option.value }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

.ts:

```
setBool(bool: boolean) {
        this.bool = bool;
    }
```

This worked in that when I clicked an option, bool was set to true so Q2 was then also shown. However, I have come across an issue in that when I unselect the options (so that none are selected), the question is obviously not hidden again.

Is there a solution so that if any of the options are selected, bool = true and if none are selected bool = false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use selectionChange event instead of click

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Select your option" [(ngModel)]="option" name="action" 
      (selectionChange)="onChange()">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of actions" [value]="option">
       {{option}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

and then you can set bool in that function

```
onChange() {
  //Do something
}
```

initialize this variable to false by default if you don't want that question to appear

Comment: That logic works well if there is only one option, however there are 5 options. If I select option 1, the boolean becomes true. If I then also select option 2, this boolean becomes false

Comment: why will it become false, if any of the options is selected set it to true else it will have its default value (false)

Comment: because I need some logic to make it false when the options are unclicked - for example if they have been clicked in error

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz with at least the first case that is working

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED:**

I was able to find a solution by using

```
(selectionChange)="onChange()"
```

```
        if(this.Q1.value != ""){
            this.bool = true;
        } else {
            this.bool = false;
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mentioned in my answer